# El ciclo while sigue iterando con valores == 0

Tags: python

Tuve que hacer, como ejercicio para python, un validador de tarjetas de crédito. Todas las funciones andan bien, solo que...

En la parte final dentro del ciclo `while numeroIntentos != 0`, el contador funciona bien, solo que cuando llega a 0, en lugar de parar la iteración y mostrar el mensaje final, el ciclo continúa con *...le quedan 0 intentos:* y aunque coloque un número válido, me devuelve el último mensaje de *"Lo siento, se le acabaron los intentos, espere un momento y vuelva a intentarlo".* Cuando en su lugar debería el último intento ser con  `numeroIntentos == 1`. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
#El validador contiene todas las demas funciones de verificacion
def validador(*args):
    return (isdigit(num)
        and tiene19(num)
        and empiezacon456(num)
        and gruposde4(num)
        and consecutivos(num))

#Se verifican que los datos ingresados sean solo digitos
def isdigit(*args):
    numSinSepa = num.replace("-", "")
    return numSinSepa.isdigit()

#Se verifican que la cantidad de caracteres ingresados sean 19
def tiene19(*args):
    return len(num) == 19

#Se verifica que la cadena ingresada comience con 4, 5 o 6
def empiezacon456(*args):
    return num.startswith ("4" or "5" or "6")

#Se verifica que la cadena pueda dividirse en 4 grupos de 4
def gruposde4(*args):
    numSep = num.replace("-", " ")
    numsplit = numSep.split()
    return (len(numsplit)==4 
        and len(numsplit[0])==4 
        and len(numsplit[1])==4 
        and len(numsplit[2])==4 
        and len(numsplit[3])==4)

#Se verifica que no haya mas de 3 caracteres iguales consecutivos
def consecutivos(*args):
    numSinSep = num.replace("-", "")
    i = 0
    while i < len(numSinSep) - 3:
        if (numSinSep[i] == numSinSep[i + 1] 
        and numSinSep[i] == numSinSep[i + 2] 
        and numSinSep[i] == numSinSep[i + 3]):
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

#Se pide que ingrese el numero, ofreciendo 5 intentos
numeroIntentos = 5
print ("Tiene", numeroIntentos, "intentos.")
num = input("Ingrese el número de la tarjeta: ")

#Se verifican los numeros de intentos disponibles, y se ejecuta el validador
while numeroIntentos > 0:
    if validador(num):
        print ("Su número ingresado es válido.")
        exit()
    else:
        numeroIntentos -= 1
        print ("Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan", numeroIntentos, "intentos.")
        num = input("Por favor ingreselo nuevamente: ")
print("Lo siento, se le acabaron los intentos, espere un momento y vuelva a intentarlo.")
```

Comment: Puedes intentar validar que el numero de intentos sea mayor a 0, así el while no se va de largo y cuando llegue a cero pues papara, ya que 0 no es mayor a 0.

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero gracias por responder! ya lo intente y el problema sigue siendo el mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que reordenar el código:

```
#Se pide que ingrese el numero, ofreciendo 5 intentos
print ("Tiene 5 intentos.")
num = input("Ingrese el número de la tarjeta: ")
numeroIntentos = 4

#Se verifican los numeros de intentos disponibles, y se ejecuta el validador
while not validador(num) and numeroIntentos > 0:
    print ("Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan", numeroIntentos, "intentos.")
    num = input("Por favor ingreselo nuevamente: ")
    numeroIntentos -= 1

if numeroIntentos:
    print("Su número ingresado es válido.")
else:
    print("Lo siento, se le acabaron los intentos, espere un momento y vuelva a intentarlo.")
```

Como ya pediste el primer número, hay que entrar al ciclo con `numeroIntentos` en 4, no en cinco.

Hay que ejecutar el ciclo sólo si la validación falla tras el primer intento, y salir cuando sea válido o la cuenta llegue a cero.

Hay que rebajar la cuenta, **después** de imprimir el mensaje.

#### Demo

```
Tiene 5 intentos.
Ingrese el número de la tarjeta: 1
Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan 4 intentos.
Por favor ingreselo nuevamente: 2
Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan 3 intentos.
Por favor ingreselo nuevamente: 3
Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan 2 intentos.
Por favor ingreselo nuevamente: 4
Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan 1 intentos.
Por favor ingreselo nuevamente: 5
Lo siento, se le acabaron los intentos, espere un momento y vuelva a intentarlo.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Con un número válido:

```
Tiene 5 intentos.
Ingrese el número de la tarjeta: 4567-1234-1234-1234
Su número ingresado es válido.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder siempre! que tengas un excelente dia!!

Comment: aun asi, cuando me dice "Su número ingresado no es válido, le quedan 1 intentos." e ingreso un numero válido, me dice: "Lo siento, se le acabaron los intentos, espere un momento y vuelva a intentarlo."

Comment: ejemplo de numero valido: 4567-1234-1234-1234